# ValidationSummary on partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a page which lists all the students and prompts user to add new one.

Student Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.getStudents());
}

public ActionResult Create(Student student)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //some code here
    }
    else
    {
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Partial view 'Index':

```
@model IEnumerable<Student>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentName)
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentName)
}
@{ Html.RenderAction("Create", "Student"); }
```

Partial view 'Create':

```
@model Student
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Student", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "")
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentName)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentName, "")
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

My problem:

When I post the form `Create` action invoked and if the model is invalid it redirects to the `Index` without display `ValidationMessage` and `ValidationSummary`.

What should I change to keep error messages ?

Comment: you should return to the same view like return this.view(your model) instead of redirecttoAction

Comment: @frebin francis, if I do I get only Create view without the List view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a view model to accomplish your requirement for listing the students and creating the students from a single page.

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
   public IEnumerable<Student> Students {get;set;}

   public Student NewStudent {get;set;}
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model IndexViewModel //Have the fully qualified model name here
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StudentName)
@foreach (var item in Model.Students) {
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StudentName)
}
@{ Html.RenderAction("Create", "Student", Model.NewStudent); }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new IndexViewModel();
    viewModel.Students = db.getStudents();
    viewModel.NewStudent = new Student();
    return View(db.getStudents());
}

public ActionResult Create(Student student)
{
    var viewModel = new IndexViewModel();            

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Create student
        // Do something else
    }
    else
    {
       viewModel.Students = db.getStudents();
       viewModel.NewStudent = student;
       return View("Index", viewModel);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. This is just a sample. You can refactor the code that creates the view model.